# Reliable self-start minecart booster in smp?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

In my smp server, I've been creating a rail system to travel long distances between minecart stations.  At each station I utilize track switches to set your destination, and a self start booster to get you on your way.  Each station has one of these, https://minecraft.wiki/w/Minecart_booster#Switch-triggered_booster

I found that much of the time, the booster cart wouldn't reset above the door properly, so I added an uphill booster to boost the booster cart, which will get it into place most of the time.  However, people still have problems with the booster cart not resetting properly, or even disappearing all together.

Is there a more reliable self-start booster I can utilize in my stations?

Comment: I recommend checking out [Bob's Minecart Tutorials](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0v5cAFYouWY&feature=related). Most of the tracks are stable in smp, although not self-starting.

Comment: This is all broken now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use bob's mine-cart station:

and

he is using wood and stone pressure plates to recognize empty mine-carts and all you have to do is sit in the mine-cart and it's automatically will push you, I used it, and it worked very well. For mine-carts stack you can you water flow like here:

he made it really cool, but it's a none stop station. you can combine it and get exactly what you need!

Answer (score 3):

Beware that side-by-side boosters as depicted here will soon be obsolete!  With 1.6, Notch is fixing the side-by-side boosting glitch that carts exhibit on each other.  Your best bet is to use [powered rails](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Powered_Rail), possibly in conjunction with [detector rails](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Detector_Rail) (useful for one-way boosting among other things).

If you'd like the powered rails to just be always-on, the cheapest solution is probably to put a lever next to the powered rail, as it only costs one cobblestone and one brick (and has the advantage over redstone torches of being toggle-able without having to break it).

Comment: Bit of a tense mix up there ;)

Answer (score 2):

ive designed a really simple one. never had ANY trouble with it. check out my youtube video on how to make it

Comment: Pretty slick :)

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using minecart mania if you have bukkit installed on the server.  You can find it [here](http://forums.bukkit.org/threads/mech-minecart-mania-1-03a-460-506-531-1-3-compatible.388/).  It has many booster type blocks that can be used to create quite complex stations with ease and in a very small space.

Answer (score 0):

I find the door boosters (switch triggered as you linked to, though that seems like a generically awful name) to be the most reliable in SMP.

Make sure you 1: have that piece of ladder to hold it in place properly.  And 2: give the cart enough momentum to easily travel into the holding slot above the door.

You mention you added an uphill booster to throw the cart into place above the door, so I'd assume you are good on the second concern.  What do you mean not resetting properly?  Where does the cart go exactly?

Also, are you stacking multiple carts or just one?  A quicker redstone solution is needed (pulse generator/edge detector) to properly manage multiple carts on top of one another (a pez dispenser) to ensure only one drops at a time from the door.

Lastly, the disappearing problem could be a bug related to Bukkit mod.  A recent commit causes carts to not render visually where you expect them to be.  They are still there, but won't render until they are moved.  Sometimes people assume they aren't there, add more carts/etc and then it's just pure havoc as to what happens.